# Word for results after a long period of time?

Tags: word-request

Sometimes you want to act in a way to achieve immediate effect.

Other times, such as raising children, you want to choose a pattern, behavior, or action that will provide the best long term outcome.

I'm looking for a word [suitable for use as a tag](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/781/is-there-a-tag-for-long-term-outcomes?noredirect=1#comment1560_781) that embodies the idea of looking out for future interests.

Outcome is close, but feels like it doesn't cover a long enough period, requiring time modifiers.

Long-term-development

Success-as-adult

These are the themes I'm trying to capture.  Any words or very short phrases that would do this?

Comment: In education, people often use _life-long learning outcomes._  In a tag, _lifelong-outcomes_ would be easily understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventual, ultimate, terminal, peer pressure-resistant, lifelong, fadeproof.

Longlasting effects.  Lasting effect.  Effects that carry over into adulthood.  Permanent effects.  Persistent benefits.  Carryover results.  Indelible lessons.

Answer (score 0):

One word that comes to mind is "[sustainable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sustainable)": `able to last or continue for a long time`.  For example, "sustainable practices" are policies that are meant to promote long-term success.

But sustainability is not typically used regarding child-raising.  If you want a single word to imply both sustainability and child-raising, I think you're going to be out of luck.

"[Cultivate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cultivate)", `to grow or raise (something) under conditions that you can control`, could be coupled with "sustainability" to make a phrase such as "I want to sustainably cultivate my children's growth."